# Reimplementing numpy.add.at for older NumPy versions

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using a library that calls `np.add.at`, but my numpy version (1.7.1) is so old that it doesn't contain this feature.

My surrogate, unfortunately has different semantics:

```
def np_add_at(a, ix, b):
   a[ix] += b

a = np.array([1])
np_add_at(a, [0,0], 1)
# a is now array([2])
b = np.array([1])
np.add.at(b, [0,0], 1)
# b is now array([3])
```

Is there a way for me to tell if this issue arises and throw an exception? Ie. I would like to detect if the `ix` argument has any repetitions to at least throw an error.

To make matters worse, the way `np.add.at` is called, `ix` often takes on values such as `(None, slice(None, None, None))`.

Comment: The entire reason `at` was added was because `a[ix] += b` doesn't do what people expect and there's no good way to implement it in terms of the other tools NumPy provides.

Comment: Do you have access to `np.add.reduceat`?

Comment: @Divakar: updated the post, and yes!